# Dynamically get 'Key' with 'Value' in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

For E.g

```
 let obj = {
    key1: ["A", "B", "C"],
    key2: ["D", "E"],
    key3: ["F"]
};
```

If the Input is "A", it should return key1. Tried with the following code for different object. Any better way for current scenario?
`

```
function findKey(value) {
    var element = null;
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
        if (obj[key].value === value.toString()) {
            element = key;
            return;
        }
    });
    return element;
}
```

`

Comment: You can use `Array#indexOf()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
let obj = {
  key1: ["A", "B", "C"],
  key2: ["D", "E"],
  key3: ["F"]
};

function findKey(value) {
  return Object.keys(obj).find(key => obj[key].includes(value));
}

console.log(findKey("A"));
```

Another option is to reorganize the data structure into a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for quicker access:

```js
let obj = {
  key1: ["A", "B", "C"],
  key2: ["D", "E"],
  key3: ["F"]
};

let map = new Map();

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
  obj[key].forEach(value => {
    map.set(value, key);
  });
});

console.log(map.get("A"));
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. Map looks better.  Let me reorganize in to Map. Thank you castle.

Answer (score 5):

Try to use `Object.keys` which returns an array of all keys and then use `find` to get first matching element

```
let input = "A";
let result = Object.keys(obj).find(key => obj[key].indexOf(input) !== -1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try following

```js
let obj = {
    key1: ["A", "B", "C"],
    key2: ["D", "E"],
    key3: ["F"]
};
var text = "A";
var match = Object.entries(obj).find(([key, value]) => value.includes(text));

console.log(match[0]);
```

For reference, [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: The `find` callback needs to return a boolean value. It can't return the result of the `find` operation

Comment: @Bergi - Though I have updated the code because it makes more sense, however, I still doubt that why the previous will not work.

Comment: @Bergi - Now I get our message. I was not returning the value, I was returning true/false only. It was that i avoided explicitly writing it and wrote a logical true/false. Hope it clarifies and please see - i know what find returns :)